# regular expression in C# for first two char and then followed by 16 digit numbers

Tags: c#, regex

/* regular expression */

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z]\d{16}$");

/*expression validation */

if ((regex.IsMatch(this.CreditCardNumber)))
{
    // Error message to display
    result = false;
}
```

eg

```
AX411111111111111
```

above expression not working in C# any suggestions?

Comment: `new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]{2}\d{16}$");` ?

Comment: Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\s * (?=.*[1 - 9])\d +[,\.\d] +$");

if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))) {
    if (!(regex.IsMatch(val)))  {
        return res;
    } Having textbox which accepting amount in strict format -> should support up to 99999.99.For that above regex i have created but not working..I need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you have given has only `15` digits, if you put `16` digits on it, it should work with this `^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{16}$` or with Tim's suggestion.